# Switches, Lights, and Logic!

Tags: logic

Venus has switches at the top and bottom of her stairs to control the light for the stairwells. (Why she has lights on the side of her stairs, I don't know...)

She notices that when the upstairs switch is up, and the downstairs switch is down, the light is turned on.

**Questions:**
$$\\$$**(a)** Copy and complete the truth table below:

[image]

**(b)** If both the upstairs and downstairs switches are in the up position, will the light be on? Explain your reasoning.

**(c)** If the upstairs switch is in the down position, and the downstairs switch is in the up position, will the light be on? Explain.

**(d)** In general, how should the two switches be positioned such that the light is on?

I'm confused as to where to begin. Even a little hint is nice too.

Comment: You need to know (though it's not stated explicitly in the problem) that when several switches control a single light, flipping one of the switches should never do nothing -- that is, it must either turn the light on if it was off, or vice versa.

Comment: This separates the mathematicians from the realists. I'd argue you can't conclude a dang thing as some weirdo could design the switches to do anything s/he wants. But I suppose if we assume flipping any one switch always changes the state of light then it all follows. Upstairs-up&downstairs-up= opposite Upstairs-up&downstairs-down = opposite T = F = light off. Etc. The table should be straight forward. Btw. I had this light setup as a child.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: we  are wondering off into practical electrical engineering here: but it is quite normal to have a master switch that isolates an electrical circuit: when it's off, the ordinary switches have no effect. With the given observations, a skeptical realist might argue that the light could controlled by a proximity sensor that is always on when she's on the stairwell looking at the switches and that the switches might control something completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each switch can only be in 2 possible positions, up or down. So all possible states:

$$
\begin{matrix}
Upstairs & Downstairs & Light On \\
Up       & Up         &          \\
Up       & Down       & True     \\
Down     & Up         &          \\
Down     & Down       &    
\end{matrix}
$$

Notice that the light is on if the switches are in different positions. If you "toggle" one of the lights from Up/Down to, say, Up/Up, that will turn the light off. Toggle like this until you have your complete table, and the rest of the answers will come directly from that table.

(This is basically just an exclusive-or)

Comment: So the order goes False, True, True, False for the spaces under the $\text{Lights on!}$?

Comment: Yes, and you should verify *why*, too, to make sure you understand it.